# Data structure with efficient "remove" function

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I am looking for ways to improve performance bottleneck in my code.
In my code, I build a graph where each vertex maintains the lists of outgoing and incoming edges. And what is killing the performance of my code is the fact that these edges are removed very often from the lists.

Currently, my implementation is using the list available in the STL library of C++. So I was wondering if there is any data structure that provides an efficient remove function.

Below is the secion of the code where the removals of vertices take place. You can see that
in every iteration of the outer for loop
   (*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.remove(*inedge_it) is called to remove (*inedge_it) from the list of incoming edges.
Likewise in the inner for loop 
  (*outedge_it)->tgt->in_edges.remove(*outedge_it is called to remove (*outedge_it) from the list of outgoing edges.

```
int dag_vertex::eliminate( int & edge_counter )
{
    int nMults = 0;

    list<dag_edge*>::iterator inedge_it;
    list<dag_edge*>::iterator outedge_it;

    int m = in_edges.size();
    int n  = out_edges.size();

    for( inedge_it=in_edges.begin() ; inedge_it!=in_edges.end() ; inedge_it++ )
    {
        (*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.remove(*inedge_it);

        for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
        {
            (*outedge_it)->tgt->in_edges.remove(*outedge_it);

            double cij = (*inedge_it)->partial*(*outedge_it)->partial;

            nMults++;

            dag_edge * direct_link = NULL;

            list<dag_edge*>::reverse_iterator src_outedge_it;

            for( src_outedge_it=(*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.rbegin() ; src_outedge_it!=(*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.rend() ; src_outedge_it++ )
            {
                if( (*src_outedge_it)->tgt==(*outedge_it)->tgt )
                {
                    direct_link = (*src_outedge_it);
                    break;
                }
            } 

            if(direct_link)
            {
                direct_link->partial += cij;
            }else
            {
                (*outedge_it)->tgt->add_in_edge( (*inedge_it)->src , cij );
                edge_counter++;
            }
        }

        delete (*inedge_it);    
    }

    for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
    {   
        delete (*outedge_it);
    }

    in_edges.clear();
    out_edges.clear();

    edge_counter -= (m+n);

    return nMults;
}
```

Here is the definition of the function for adding an incoming edge

```
dag_edge* dag_vertex::add_in_edge(dag_vertex* src , double partial)
{
    dag_edge* the_in_edge= new dag_edge(src, this, partial);
    in_edges.push_back(the_in_edge);
    src->out_edges.push_back(the_in_edge);
    return the_in_edge;
}
```

Below is the defintion of dag_edge.

```
dag_edge::dag_edge(class dag_vertex* s, class dag_vertex* t, double cij) : 
src(s), tgt(t), partial(cij),alive(true)
{

}

dag_edge::~dag_edge()
{
     //std::cout<<"~dag_edge("<<src->idx<<","<<tgt->idx<<")"<<std::endl;
}

dag_vertex* dag_edge::getsrc()
{
    return src;
}

dag_vertex* dag_edge::gettgt()
{
    return tgt;
}

void dag_edge::dump_to_dot(FILE* file)
{
    fprintf(file,"%d->%d [label=\"%f\"]\n",src->idx, tgt->idx, partial); 
}

void dag_edge::display() 
{

}
```

Comment: Could you also include `dag_edge` definition to your question?

Comment: dag_edge is the data structure that implements edges.
DAG stands for directed-acyclic graph.

Comment: can you still show the definition please ?

Comment: i have already updated my post. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually calling remove more than necessary:

```
for( inedge_it=in_edges.begin() ; inedge_it!=in_edges.end() ; inedge_it++ )
{
    (*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.remove(*inedge_it);

    for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
    {
        (*outedge_it)->tgt->in_edges.remove(*outedge_it); // This has no dependence on inedge_it
```

Basically it ends up trying to remove the input edges from the targets multiple times, so it'll spend a lot of time trying to find edges that have already been removed.

You could extract it into a separate loop:

```
for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
{
   (*outedge_it)->tgt->in_edges.remove(*outedge_it);
}

for( inedge_it=in_edges.begin() ; inedge_it!=in_edges.end() ; inedge_it++ )
{
    (*inedge_it)->src->out_edges.remove(*inedge_it);

    for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
    {
        double cij = (*inedge_it)->partial*(*outedge_it)->partial;
```

Comment: Vaughn, you are right. Thanks a lot. Anyway, profiling reveals that the removals of vertices in the inner loop are not the hotspot.
The hotspot are the ones in the outer loop.

Comment: @takwing: interesting.  I imagine you typically have a lot more incoming edges than outgoing ones, so a lot of the time is spent looking through the list of incoming edges to find a match.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to `delete` \ `compare` \ `insert` \ `search` is using HashTables. in STL there is a `#include <map>`. Then you need two `Map` objects instead of your `vectors`. The implementation is similar, however when you perform the comparison it will be easier, and also you can have only one loop. You code is currently `O(n^3)` it will be reduced to `O(n * log n)` at best, and `O(n^2)` at worst case.

Comment: How can my code be reduced to O(n) or O(n^2) with the for loops  still there? I think the two outermost for loops are inevitably necessary. Could you give me some hint?

Now my code is O(n^6) taking into account the remove operations and the linear search in the innermost for loop.

Comment: @takwing
The point of using `Map` is the three for loops won't be there. Search in `Map` is done in `O(1)`. Have two `Map` objects, one for `inedge` and another for `outedge`. . You'll need to overhaul your entire code .. . tweaking around won't make real difference, you can use all pointers and references, parallelization but that won't improve as much as using `Map`.

Comment: @philippe couple of points: `std::map` is written in lowercase. Searching in it is `O(log n)` not `O(1)`. `std::map` is not a hash table. It is a sorted associative container, commonly implemented using a balanced tree. Hash table was added to standard library in C++11 and is called `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @Fiktik I imagined search was `O(log n)`. I'm sorry for that. I've been  writing code in `Java`, `C`, `C++`, `Python`, `Perl`, `JavaScript`, `PHP`, `Groovy` and `Lisp` this summer.

Comment: @philppe, yes, I'd love to have a look at your idea in the form of pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it would be more efficient to store edges by value in a `vector` and when you need to remove the `edge` say at index `i` you may do it by replacing the `i` edge with the last one in a `vector` and popping the last one

```
edges[i] = edges.back();
edges.pop_back();
```

It can be even more efficient if using `move semantics` for `edge`

Comment: @takwing: it's a c++ 11 feature that allows you to move the data instead of copying. Here is a good article: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_02.html